# Returning Facebook Event Venue Data (City, State, Street, Zip, Etc.)

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to list upcoming events from a Facebook page to a website. [This article](http://autobotcode.blogspot.com/2012/10/display-facebook-page-events-using-graph-api-and-fql.html)  got me 95% there.

Here is my FQL query:

```
SELECT name,start_time,end_time,location,venue,venue.city,venue.street,eid FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 137235173013656 AND start_time >= '$now') ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 0, 5
```

Unfortunately, the venue array for this event only seems to return an ID:

```
"data": [
  {
    "name": "Party for the Rest of Us 8", 
    "start_time": "2013-02-01T19:00:00-0500", 
    "end_time": null, 
    "location": "The Renaissance Ballroom", 
    "venue": {
      "id": 102464129826400
    }, 
    "eid": 365130383585238
  }
]
```

This seems strange to me, b/c when I created the event it autocompletes to a [known location](https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Renaissance-Ballroom/102464129826400) which has a city and state.

I can't manually enter the location info for the event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in one query. It's pretty straightforward to get the location data by querying the venue ID returned above: http://graph.facebook.com/102464129826400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook started changing the way venues are returned by the API in May 2012. Some venues created after that only return an ID. You can get the full address for these by doing a multiquery on the `page` table and reassembling them in your script.

This query should get you started:

```
{
  "q_events":
    "SELECT name,start_time,end_time,location,venue,eid FROM event WHERE eid = 365130383585238",
  "q_venues":
    "SELECT page_id, name, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN 
       (SELECT venue.id FROM #q_events)"
}
```

Comment: I wasn't certain how to write a multiquery, so I ended up writing to different queries. Not elegant, but it worked. :)

`$param_event = array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => "SELECT name,start_time,end_time,location,venue,eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = '$fbpageid' AND start_time >= '$now') ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 0, 1",
);
...
$param_venue = array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => "SELECT location FROM page WHERE page_id = '$venueid'",
);`